# The site toolbar looks broken in Chrome. How can I fix it?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, design

Since earlier this month, the main toolbar of the site (with links to Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, Unanswered and Ask Question) has changed, distinctly for the worse:

[image: Toolbar]

The font looks blocky and ugly, the shaded rectangle is shifted down so that it overlaps with the question titles. This looks amateurish and mostly just wrong.

This issue is present in Chrome but (apparently) not in other browsers. Is this by design, or is it a bug? If so, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I struggled with this too. It seems that it's due to a *Chrome* update. To undo this nonsense, type

```
about:flags
```

in your URL bar and click 'Enable' on the Disable DirectWrite Windows option (4th from above). This fixed it, for me at least.

[image: Crappy Update]

It may be necessary to close and reopen Chrome, or to visit `chrome://restart` on a new tab, to make this work.