# Wide Chrome (>2406 px) breaks horizontal alignment

Tags: bug, style

Not sure if this is related to [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/the-site-toolbar-looks-broken-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-it), but there's yet another formatting problem in Chrome. I'm seldom one to argue for doing it so it works vs. doing it right, but there needs to be some pragmatism: the number of Windows Chrome users strike me as a not-so-insignificant chunk.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this might be related to: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/the-site-toolbar-looks-broken-in-chrome-how-can-i-fix-it. If so, you'll find a suggested work-around in the earlier question.

Comment: @dmckee that was my thought (see link)

Comment: I suppose the real question is *does the work around in the linked Meta post fix your issue*?