# The site toolbar looks broken in Opera

Tags: discussion, bug, design

[The site toolbar looks broken in Chrome. How can I fix it?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6114)

I have the same problem but in Opera. I've read in one comment that this isn't a problem in Opera but it's for me.

Edit: This is really disturbing because in this form, the clickable area of the buttons is on the upper half of them and each time I want to click on them I've to go through the same confusion and bewilderment again and again until I remember what's going on in here.

[image]

Comment: What version of Opera do you use?

Comment: Version 26.0.1656.24. It's the latest one.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Version 12.16 on Scientific Linux 6.5 (only one in the repos). I think the newer ones are based on Chrome, hence the similar issue. Not sure what the fix would be.